# Save on Chrome's autofill from an AngularJS's single page application

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, autofill

How can I have my AngularJS single page application to register the user's input on the browser's autofill settings when submitting a form? Angular doesn't really submit the form in the "default" way, so the browser does not catch the input.

The following will NOT save in Chrome's autofill:

```
<form id="header-search" class="navbar-form form-inline" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="search" name="q" ng-model="Search.term" ng-required="true"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
</form>
```

It works with `<form action='/search'>`, but I don't it to break my SPA behavior by posting and coming back.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, it's very difficult to tell what the problem is. Using [angular forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) with an [ngSubmit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit), should allow for submitting forms in a normal enough way to trigger autocomplete.

Comment: Updated with my example.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with login form, where Chrome autofilled username and password. I added into login controller following code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.username = $('div#login input[name="username"]').val();
        $scope.password = $('div#login input[name="password"]').val();
     },300);  
});
```

You can also try to trigger input on all your input elements to force update ngModel. I think this should work too.

```
$('yourInputsIdentifier').trigger('input');
```

Comment: My models are being synced correctly, what they're not doing is saving in Chrome's autofill when I post. I don't have issues with ngModel being updated.